# Check if request is by user or by page

Tags: asp.net, request, global-asax, hotlinking

I am trying to restrict direct access and downloading of files from my resources folder. I have implemented this in my global.asax:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpRequest request = application.Context.Request;

    if (request.Url.ToString().Contains(@"/resources/"))
    {
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Redirect(@"http://mysitename.com/download_restriction.aspx");
    }
}
```

It works however, it restricts my pages from using the resources as well... Can I somehow check if the request is being done from one of my pages?

Comment: This isn't a `asp-classic` question - it's ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

**use session variable to know that you have come from your application**